# Externalizing Run configurations for Grails app

Tags: java, intellij-idea, grails, environment-variables, properties-file

Is there a way to externalize the run config for per environment configurations with Grails 3 applications?
I am aware that there are run config arguments that allow one to run their application under a dev, prod, test, etc environment, but I was wondering if there is a variable, for example "grails.env" that I can change in a properties, YAML, config, or other file that can be read at run time that will do this for me.

This is just to avoid confusion between the application being tested and run in one setting/environment(physical environment like my local machine), then being given to another individual or team to run elsewhere.
The goal is to configure or set this variable so the run team/individual wont need to know or change the run commands.

Im aware of how to configure the environment with the command line, and within intelliJ and Eclipse. I'm wondering if there is a way to default this in perhaps a file that is read instead.
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

> I'm not to sure what is confusing you here but let me try and see if I can point you in the right direction

From the documentation here: http://docs.grails.org/latest/guide/conf.html#environments your application can be delivered as a package war file to the target user to have tested, and the war file can be created with any of of the environment configurations

```
grails test war
```

Since the command is can be run in the console, you could run with system properties like this:

```
grails $ENVIRONMENT war
```

Hope this helps

> Update 2

By default the grails run-app runs with the dev environment, but you can force an environment by doing

```
grails $env run-app
```

If you want some default configurations to be run when you use the run-app command, then you should make sure that configuration is not in the environment block in either application.yml or application.groovy

```
Example of configuration in the environment block:
-----------------------------------------------------
environment{
     development{
               appConfig{
                      ishybrid = true
               }
     }
}
```

```
Example of configuration not in any environment block:
-------------------------------------------------------
appConfig{
      ishybrid = true
}
environment{
      development{
               //other configs
      }
}
```

So basically depending on what you exclude from the environment block configuration is what will be configured as the default configuration for your application to run.

Hope this helps better?

Comment: Thanks for your input.
What im looking for, is if there is a way to specify/configure WITHIN the project/application itself, what environment to run or build it under by default.
Rather than specify this when giving the run command.
Also, which environment does it run under by default to begin with?
Or am i completely off because in order to build or run a grails app, you have to specify the environment
ie. (grails [default] war)